# Copying text from one textarea element to another in real-time

Tags: javascript, textarea, mouseevent, keyboard-events, textselection

I want to copy input from one textarea to another textarea in real-time. This is not a HTML editor or rich text editor. Just plain simple text without any markup.

This is what I am doing:

a. I can detect the point at which the cursor was clicked in the source text area using the following (on mouseup)

```
 $("#txt1")[0].selectionStart)
```

b. I can detect the text selection using *selectionStart* and *selectionEnd* properties on mouseup.
This allows me to keep track of delete to be reflected in the other textarea. That is if delete is the key pressed, and a selection was made I know what was deleted to be relected in the target text area.

c. Where I am stuck is the simple issue of new characters entered. I think keeping track of key pressed would be the inefficient approach as I would have to check if control, alt, shift keys, among others were also held down. Besides there is the issue of repeatedy keys presses. *The efficient way is possibly to get the characters actually entered from the source text area* and NOT based upon key pressed.

Questions:
How do I get characters entered in the source textarea?

Is there a better way to update the target textarea in real-time? One way will be to continually update the content from the source to the target at regular interval but that would be inefficient. Any other approach?

I am open to using a contentEditable div in place of a textarea.

I need a solution that can work across different device types.

Comment: Please always include the relevant code that you are working with in your question. I would think that someone with your rep. would know that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Programming questions != inclusion of code.  There is a lot more to programming than writing code. I would think that someone with your rep. should certainly know that.

Comment: Instead of being snarky, realize that there are always multiple ways to solve a problem. If we can't see the code you are using, we can't give you the best possible solution (or one that may even work within your code). And yes, you've been here long enough that you should know that.

Comment: I've taken a guess and provided something that seems to do what you are asking for below, but maybe not since I can't see what you are actually doing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Agreed that I could have done better in this specific question and should have but I beg to disagree with the comment that all programming questions should always be accompanied by code. Anyhow, thanks for the answer. Will try to add code, when possible, in the future.

Comment: I said that you should always include the ***relevant*** code in your question. It's true that not all programming questions need code (i.e. "What is a closure?"), but yours describes what it does in words, when just showing the code would speak larger volumes and let others know how to best provide code that answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get characters entered in the source textarea?

Just handle the `input` event of the first `textarea` and make the second `textarea` have the same value as the first.

```js
let two = document.getElementById("two");
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input", function(){
  two.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```